# Removing autostart program from .bashrc

Tags: pi-3, python, bash

Hello guys I made a really dumb mistake by adding a python script in .bashrc. I wanted to make this script autostart and followed a tutorial, where it said i should add it to .bashrc. Later on i read that you shouldn t do that. The script is a while Method so it wont stop. 
Now my problem is that everytime i start the terminal the script opens and i can t type stuff into it to remove it. 
Does somebody know how i can remove the script out of the .bashrc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You COULD fix this by modifying the SD Card on a Linux system.

You can do this on the Pi itself by rebooting to a root shell and can repair most such problems on the Pi.

```
1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as
read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`
```

You should then be able to edit .bashrc.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `.bashrc` you want will be at `/home/pi/.bashrc` and not `~/.bashrc` as you're logged in as `root`.