# desktop not loading

Tags: desktop

I've recently encountered a problem on my raspberry pi 3 not loading desktop.  I thought it was due to some extra large files I had, so I deleted those but desktop still does not load.  I typed in startx
from command line-  I got the error message:

```
Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock
xinit:  giving up
init:   unable to connect to X server:  Connection refused
init:   server error
```

Comment: what research have you done?

Comment: I've seen where people recommend removing /home/username/.XAuthority*

Comment: And I get error- no such file.  I've also tried to reinstall x.org- it says not enough room on device.  I also see that I can't change my password.

Comment: so, it worked, and then one day stopped working? and .. which files did you delete

Comment: If you had WiFi ON and not secured, local hackers can get in fast and 'own' your Pi in seconds. After you load in Rasbian via Ethernet you should shut off WiFi and do security protocols. Give 'root' user a long password. Create several fake users with good passwords. Get rid of the user 'pi'. See website for many security procedures to take. Right now you may need a new or re-built SD card.

Comment: @Kevin, google `Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock`

Comment: I think it may possibly be that I need to expand filesystem on my sd card?  I'm going to google how to do that from a Mac.  Right now I can't even get to a prompt on the pi.  It tries to load the desktop and then goes to a blank screen.

Comment: If you can get to the command line post the output of `df -h /`
If you can't follow the instructions in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93608/8697 to get to a root shell.

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t just reflash your SD Card?

Comment: @CoderMike do you lose everything when you do that?

Comment: Yes. If you've got command line access you could copy files off first.